# DRS: Unknown JNLP Location

Tags: java

We are using Deployment Rule Sets to limit access to the older JRE to well-known applications but are running into a problem.

One business critical applications has the following properties (*s to protect info):

```
title: Enterprise Services Repository
location: null
jar location: http://app.*.com:52400/rep/repository/*.jar
jar version: null
isArtifact: true
```

The application downloads a .jnlp file, and uses java web start to execute. 
Since the location is null, this application cannot be targeted by a location rule. And the certificate hash method only works when the application is cached (being ran more than once). If cache storing is off, which is the case in some situations, how can this application be targeted? Or at least told to run with an older JRE on start?

This problem is specifically noted in [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023343)

Thanks!